# How to have properties of custom control in xaml when we drag that control?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have created a custom control for `TextBox` with soem `DependencyProperties` and some simple properties, now, when I drag my custom control from ToolBox to designer then I want to have **properties which are declared in custom control to appear in XAML by default.**

Does anyone have idea about it?

Looking forward for quick reply.

Samir

Answer (score 0):

We can add the properties to the control by default while you are dragging from ToolBox to the designer..

Please refer the below msdn documentation..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb907306(v=vs.90).aspx

i think it will help you to resolve the problem..